# How are internal InputStreams of a URLConnection closed

Tags: java, url, inputstream

I'm implementing a custom protocol handler and just came accross this code in the JDK.

```
 public Object getContent() throws IOException {
     // Must call getInputStream before GetHeaderField gets called
     // so that FileNotFoundException has a chance to be thrown up
     // from here without being caught.
     getInputStream();
     return getContentHandler().getContent(this);
 }
```

See [URLConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/net/URLConnection.java/#734)

I thought that `InputStream`s should be closed. Since the `getInputStream()` method's return value is not saved it can not be accessed and therefore not closed.

I thought that this could lead to open file descriptors in case of a `file://` protocol and wrote that test program.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test", "test");
URL url = tempFile.toURI().toURL();
URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();

// getContent() should create 2 InputStreams
InputStream content = (InputStream) openConnection.getContent();
content.close(); // only one is closed

boolean deleted = tempFile.delete();
System.out.println("Temp file deleted " + deleted);
```

But the result is

```
Temp file deleted true
```

If I comment out the `content.close()` I get

```
Temp file deleted false
```

I'm just confused now how I should implement my `URLConnection`.

- Should I implement finalize on my `InputStream`s and close them
- Should I use use `WeakReference`s to the streams to 'auto' close

Both options look like a workaround.

Do I miss something?

**EDIT**

I also thought  that each call to `getInputStream` should return the same instance, because it is not named `openInputStream` or something.

This would explain why the `FileURLConnection` works in my example. But it seems weird that the `getContent` method assumes that the `ContentHandler` will access the same `InputStream` and thus the stream will be closed after the content is read.

Sure it seems obvious that I must read the content to create a content object, but if I just return a lazy content object the stream might not be closed.

Also the [`ContentHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ContentHandler.html#getContent-java.net.URLConnection-) javadoc does not say that the `ContentHandler` must close the `InputStream`

> Given a URL connect stream positioned at the beginning of the representation of an object, this method reads that stream and creates an object from it.

Comment: There is no actual problem here. Be happy.

Comment: @EJP Maybe you're right and I'm just digging too deep. Eventually I'm currently making a philosophical problem out  of it. I will think about it and wait for more feedback. Thanks.